# how to pass a database retrieved value to jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I written a program to retrieve data from database in servlets.now I want pass this value to jsp as a hyperlink. How to do this?

This is my servlet code what I wrote:

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.sql.*;
  import javax.servlet.*;
  import javax.servlet.http.*;

  public class ViewServlet extends HttpServlet{
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
  res.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
  Connection con;
  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;
  String acid = null;
  try{
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSN","scott","krishna");
  stmt = con.createStatement();
  rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select id from custm where name='jai'");
  req.setAttribute(acid,rs);
  req.getRequestDispatcher("my_jsp_page.jsp").forward(req, res); 
   }
  catch (Exception e){
  pw.println(e);
  }
  }
```

}

Now I edited the code now its saying cannot call `setAttribute` with null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For extracting value from resultset:

```
while (rs.next()) {
String acid = rs.getString("id");
}
```

You can store values in Request scope using setAttribute() method....
In jsp you can retrieve it using expression language...

In servlet

```
request.setAttribute("acId",acid);
```

In jsp:

```
${acId}
```

There is also other way...
You can also use scriplets for displaying purpose in jsp..
for example....

```
<%  
      String str = (String)request.getAttribute("acId");
%>
Value is :: <%= str %>
```

for calling jsp from servlet use :

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("your.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Comment: then how to retrieve that value in jsp?

Comment: how to call a jsp from servlet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8824/discussion-between-sevak-and-krishna-bhargavi)

Comment: @krishna bhargavi : you can call servlet from jsp as follows:  
<a href="HomePage"> ${str} </a>
here "HomePage" is servlet url-pattern...